# Embedded Service: Problem with Multiple Components on a Web Page with Lightning Out

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-out, embedded-services

We are using a lightning app with embedded service. we used the instructions given [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.snapins_web_dev.meta/snapins_web_dev/embedded_web_multiple_components.htm). The chat button appears on the page but we keep getting this error:

```
{
    component: "markup://embeddedService:sidebar", 
    componentStack: "[ltng:outAppUnstyled] > [embeddedService:sidebar] > [embeddedService:sidebar]", 
    action: null, 
    name: "SyntaxError", message: "Error in $A.getCallback() [Unexpected end of JSON …debarController/ACTION$getDeploymentConfiguration", …
}
action: null
component: "markup://embeddedService:sidebar"
componentStack: "[ltng:outAppUnstyled] > [embeddedService:sidebar] > [embeddedService:sidebar]"
data: null
handled: false
id: 1174708058
message: "Error in $A.getCallback() [Unexpected end of JSON input]↵Callback 
failed: serviceComponent://ui.embeddedservice.aura.components.controller.SidebarController/ACTION$getDeploymentConfiguration"
name: "SyntaxError"reported: falseseverity: undefinedsf: (9) [d, d, d, d, d, d, d, d, d]stackFrames: (9) [d, d, d, d, d, d, d, d, d]
stackTrace: "Object.eval()@https://xxx.cs123.force.com/components/embeddedService/sidebar.js:30:393"
stacktraceIdGen: "markup://embeddedService:sidebar$Object.eval$Error in $A.getCallback()"stacktraceIdGen
Modifier: nulltf: "serviceComponent://ui.embeddedservice.aura.components.controller.SidebarController/ACTION$getDeploymentConfiguration@markup://embeddedService:sidebar↵Object.eval()@https://guitar-deltak-community.cs123.force.com/components/embeddedService/sidebar.js:30:393"__proto__: 
Error
    at new Aura.externalLibraries (https://static.lightning.force.com/cs123/auraFW/javascript/BcWxSGldKzy83CHM8lFYMg/aura_prod.js:300:363)
    at https://static.lightning.force.com/cs123/auraFW/javascript/BcWxSGldKzy83CHM8lFYMg/aura_prod.js:65:1
```

Our code looks something like this:

```
$Lightning.use(
    "embeddedService:sidebarApp",
    function () {
        $Lightning.createComponent(
            "c:HelloWorld",
            document.body,
            function (cmp) {
                console.log("callback");
            }
        );
    },
    “https://xxx.cs123.force.com/application”
);
```

> UPDATE-1:

Here is my lightning web component code:

```
import { LightningElement, api } from 'lwc';

export default class HellowWorld extends LightningElement {
    @api msg = 'Test!';

    clicked() {
        alert("Hi");
    }
}
```

and my lightning out code is:

```
$Lightning.use(
    "embeddedService:sidebarApp",
    function () {
        $Lightning.createComponent(
            "c:HelloWorld",
            { msg : "Hi!" },
            document.body,
            function (cmp) {
                console.log("callback");
            }
        );
    },
    “https://xxx.cs123.force.com/application”
);
```

But still it gives same error on click on the chat button. Just to clarify, the page comes up and we see the snap-in chat as well. The error that I have shared is on click of the chat button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We had raised a case with Salesforce on this. It turns out the issue was that we were using `$Lightning.use` in a VF page that was in different org than where we had enabled the live agent. Apparently both the `$Lightning.use` and live agent should be in same org for it to work. We tested it and want to confirm this works!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you dont provide param in your input as indicated in [the documentation you give](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.snapins_web_dev.meta/snapins_web_dev/embedded_web_multiple_components.htm) and this could explain the error =>

> message: "Error in $A.getCallback() [**Unexpected end of JSON input**]

[image]

For a more explicite exemple, you can see  [Andres Perez exemple](https://medium.com/@ElToroIT/lightning-web-components-support-lightning-out-5a79c513302f)

```
<body>
    <div id="lwcLightning"></div>
</body>
    <script>
    $Lightning.use(
        "<%- appName %>",
        () => {         
            $Lightning.createComponent(
                "<%- lwcCmpName %>",
                { msg: "It works (LWC)!" },
                "lwcLightning",
                (cmp) => {
                    console.log("LWC component was created");
                }
            );
        },
        "<%- lightningServerUrl %>",
        "<%- accessToken %>"
    );
</script>
```

Comment: we tried the code from the link you provided. we are able to embed 2 components. The problem is when we use `embeddedService:sidebarApp` as appName, it shows the chat but on clicking we get the above error. It seems an issue with embedded service and was hoping if someone tried doing something similar.

Comment: Can you add your c:HelloWorld code ? It really looks like you need to provide some parameters in the red box I drow in my answer

Comment: I have updated the original post with the details. Also wanted to clarify that the page does come up. The issue is that snap-in chat doesn't expand.

Comment: Does it change anything if you replace **document.body** by the div id where you call the component (like the exemple I provide)?

Comment: We just tried with div id but that did not work even with div id. The error seems to be coming from this script https://service.force.com/embeddedservice/5.0/esw.min.js